# NuxtJs how to use axios filter api?

Tags: vuejs2, axios, nuxt.js

There are too many api data, I want to filter it because i need to put api in cookie and save it.
If can't filter the api data, i can't save all of it to the cookie.

TypeError
this.homeProdsx.map is not a function

> ```
> async asyncData({ $axios, params }) {
>     const homeProds = await $axios.$get(process.env.backendurl + '/home-page-alls?slug=' + params.slug)
>     let homeProdsx = homeProds[0] 
>     return { homeProdsx }
> },
> computed:{
>     filteredapi(){
>         return this.homeProdsx.map(({ id, title, price,  }) => ({ id, title, price }))
>     },
> },
> ```

Comment: Feel free to accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem solved

get one more api but dont `let homeProdsx = homeProds[0]`

```
async asyncData({ $axios, params }) {
    const homeProds = await $axios.$get(process.env.backendurl + '/home-page-alls?slug=' + params.slug)
    let homeProdsx = homeProds[0]

    const testx = await $axios.$get(process.env.backendurl + '/home-page-alls?slug=' + params.slug)
    return { homeProdsx, testx}
},
```

here is computed

```
computed: {
    filteredapi(){
        return this.testx.map(({ id, title, price, gg, homeitem, int, }) => ({ id, title, price, gg, homeitem, int }))
    },

},
```

Answer (score 0):

You can probably just try `this.homeProdsx?.map` to see if `homeProdsx` is available before calling the method.

More info about optional chaining can be found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

Comment: thanks but not work this api is available before calling the method.
`_this$homeProdsx.map is not a function`

Comment: @lsfsteve are you using a client side navigation to trigger `asyncData`? Are you sure there is no typo here or anything relevant missing?

Comment: I using Strapi to make my api, i think the problem is  
`let homeProdsx = homeProds[0]`  it will make api become a object not array so cant use `.map` but i need to use`let homeProdsx = homeProds[0]` because is _slug.vue cant using `v-for`

i have to try
 `const homeProds = await $axios.$get(process.env.backendurl + '/home-page-alls`

`  let homeProdsx = homeProds `

`  return { homeProdsx } `

`<div v-for="homeproduct ,idx" in homeProdsx  :key>
    {{ homeproduct }}
<div> `

it will be work to call
but when i use[0] it failed
~ thanks